# JUnit verbose output

Tags: java, junit, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric test runner and unfortunately my test hangs (not test but somwehre in the runner). Are there any flag for JUnit, JVM to print any verbose information so I have more  insights where it could hang?

Comment: Eugen, if you can run the tests in debug mode from your IDE, you'll find that there's a *pause* button. Pause the execution and see which thread is waiting for something (an http connection?) or in an infinite loop, or any other reason.

Comment: Thank you reply. I see that "Reference Handler" and "Finalizer" wait when pause. But this doesn't give more insights

Comment: I have the feeling (but I might be completely wrong) that there could be a user thread running, and that's why JUnit never terminates... Although you can see only two threads when you pause the application. Very strange :S

Comment: Thank you reply and for the suggestion! I've tried to pause and see that process is going and TestRunner doing something. Put it as answer I will accept

Comment: I'm glad my comment was of use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling (but I might be completely wrong) that there could be a user thread running, and that's why JUnit never terminates.

Although you can see only two threads when you pause the application...

Comment: I see more threads. I was focusing on that are paused. But should be looking into running threads also